# How to resize buttons and frame in CustomTkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter, modern-ui

I need to resize buttons and button frame, but when I use the arguments (width and height) I don't see any effects. By the following the code:

`

```
# Creazione della finestra principale
root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("CCE_tool")
root.configure(fg_color="#282035")
root.geometry("900x550")
root.resizable(True, True)

# Utilizza ctk.CTkLabel invece di ctk.CTkLabel per creare l'etichetta
program_name = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="C.C.E. Tool", font=('Avantstile
Regular', 80),
fg_color="transparent", text_color=("#FF79C6")) 
program_name.pack(pady=40)

# Creazione di un frame per contenere i bottoni
button_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root, corner_radius=0)
button_frame.pack(pady=80)
button_frame.configure(fg_color="transparent")

# Creazione del primo CustomButton
install_button1 = root.main_button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(button_frame, text="Installazione rapida",
bg_color="transparent", fg_color="transparent", border_width=1, corner_radius=0,
border_color="#9C92AD", text_color=("#F8F8F8", "gray90"), hover_color
("#9C92AD", "gray70"), command=install_addon_wrapper,)
install_button1.pack(side="left", pady=40, padx=15, expand=True)

# Creazione del secondo CustomButton
install_button2 = ctk.CTkButton(button_frame, text="Installazione singoli componenti",
bg_color="transparent", fg_color="transparent", border_width=1, corner_radius=0,
border_color="#9C92AD", text_color=("#F8F8F8", "gray90"), hover_color=("#9C92AD", "gray70"),
command=install_drivers)
install_button2.pack(side="left", pady=40, padx=15, expand=True)`
```

I try to use widht and height both in the frame and for the buttons, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an issue with your code, this is an issue with CTk where it doesn't resize the widget.

the fix is to run another script then run the main script and it should work.